# Rails RESTful routing with security in mind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

If you are not using all of the RESTful routes that are included in a resources route declaration, would it be best practice to declare the routes that you will be using explicitly?

Is there a way to have only certain RESTful routes declared in Rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical [Rails guides have a section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created) on restricting RESTful routes:

You can restrict resourceful routes to *include* certain actions:

```
resources :photos, only: [:index, :show]
```

Or, alternative, you can explicitly *exclude* them:

```
resources :photos, except: [:new, :update]
```

Comment: So is it best practice to be prescriptive (and restrict more aggressively) or are open REST routes really not that much of an issue?

Comment: RESTful routes that aren't routed to a controller action will throw a 404 error in production, so there's not a particularly big reason to worry, IMO. However, if you are certain that you will not need certain actions, then there's no reason why you shouldn't be proactively prescriptive as you've suggested. That said, I don't think it's necessarily _best practice_ to do so – you won't have measurable performance benefits either way (in production, at least).

Comment: Does that answer your question?